# How do I create a system user in Atlas App Services?

Tags: mongodb

[image]

How do I create a system user? The goal is using this user as an administrator.

I can only create **normal** (client) and **server** (something like client) users, but I'm unable to create a system user.

I tried the Atlas App Services Admin Rest API but there I can do just the same I can here.

I see that a possible solution is adding **custom user data** but there isn't a way in the console.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

A server user is for backend access to your database. This may be useful if you are looking to perform backend database administration.

When you use Atlas App Services, you are creating users for frontend access to user-appropriate data. If you want to create users on the frontend with a role/privilege of 'Administrator', then you need to implement that logic.

You can create custom data for users, which is a separate document linked to the user with additional fields. A simple implementation would be a custom field 'isAdmin'.

A rule would need to be implemented to only give your frontend users access to restricted data once 'isAdmin' === true. For example:

```
{
  "%%true": {"%%user.custom_data.isAdmin"}
}
```

For more rule examples: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/rules/examples/